# Output voltage of NPC1403 boost converter circuit 0 during simluation

Tags: dc-dc-converter, simulation, boost, buck-boost

Currently, for my needs I'm trying to boost a 5v input to 15v with a minimum of 20ma current at the output. I found the NPC1403 to require my needs however, when i'm trying to simulate using EasyEDA my output voltage is constantly 0. I'm currently doing a transient analysis with 1s steps and a maximum time of 100s. I feel like there is a minor issue that i'm messing up but have been unable to figure out what. The current circuit setup can be seen below.[image: ost]

Answer (score 0):

There is something funky about this circuit.
The feedback voltage is 0. So there's that. I tried replacing the diode with another variant and landed on 4.7V as the output voltage .. If I were you, I would choose a new DCDC and try that :)
I think I got the wrong pictures where I use 3.6V as Vin and tried putting a dummy load on the circuit :) Result is still the same..

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Ah i see, i'm going to look at a couple other DCDC converters.